# Can't write the following in latex

Tags: equations

[image]am I to write d solving for a,1 a2 before begin equation [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A tip: put your code directly, not an image of it; if you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 3):

You really need to provide code rather than images of code, but a simple examination of your graphic and code image would lead one in this direction for a fix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Solving for $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, $a_4$, and $a_5$ in 
(3.11)% SHOULD USE \label \ref MECHANISM INSTEAD
\begin{align}
a_0 &= y_n\\
a_1 &= f_n\\
a_2 &= \frac{25f_n - 48 f_{\frac{1}{4}+n} + 36 f_{\frac{1}{2}+n} - 16 f_{\frac{3}{4}+n} 
      + 3 f_{1+n}} {6n}
\end{align}
Replacing $a_0$, $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, $a_4$, and $a_5$ in 
(3.12)% SHOULD USE \label \ref MECHANISM INSTEAD
...
\end{document}
```

[image]

It looks, from the types of errors in your code, as if you really need to start with a basic tutorial on LaTeX; in particular, the use of math mode versus text mode and its basic rules.

Here might be a good place to start: [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner)